# PyQt5 designer allow resize of specific widgets within an interface

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5

I have 2 widgets arranged in a vertical layout in my window, with one of them being the main application and the one at the bottom being a terminal. However, I want the terminal to be able to be "minimized" by the user, similar to how you can miminize vscode terminals. Is there a way to add this in designer?

Comment: "minimized" how? And by what? Designer can only work with established signals and compatible slots. If you have a togglable button, then connect its `toggled` signal to the `visibility` property of the target widget, assuming you want to *hide* it. If you want to change its size, then you can't do that from Designer, it has to be done by code.

Comment: @musicamante not so much of removing the entire widget, as it's a way to adjust the size of the 2 widgets. Like if you try to drag the border between the widgets, it will reduce the size of one while expanding another. I can understand not being able to do that within designer, but is there a way to drag an object such that it moves up and down and adjusts the size of objects around it?

Comment: Use [QSplitter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html). In Designer select two *non layed out* widgets and select "Lay out horizontally/verticall in splitter".